# Does a convention about the structure of a class exist?

Tags: java, conventions

When I write a class in Java, it (almost) always looks like this:

```
public class MyClass {

    // attributes

    // constructors

    // methods:
    //   * "interesting" methods
    //   * getters and setters
    //   * toString / equals / hashCode
}
```

Especially, I always write all attributes at the beginning.

Is there a convention how to structure classes in Java?

I couldn't find it in the [Oracle Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf). I am interested in sources (e.g. other style guides like [Mozilla Coding Style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Developer_Guide/Coding_Style) or books), because I am a Java tutor and I would like to give my students more than "I have learned it that way so you should also do it like this". And if there are reasons / sources that propose other structures within a class, I'd also be happy to know that.

edit: Although I am interested in your thoughts, I think I should stress that **I expect sources**. Personal experience is interesting, but I also made the experience that the structure above is common. But I want to give my students something more than the vague impression, that everybody seems to use this structure. Especially, as some of them don't use it.

Comment: The structure you showed above is very common. But as always coding conventions are a matter of the development team or the company you work at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read more carefully: The Oracle Coding conventions you linked to write in section 3.1.3:

> The following table describes the parts of a class or interface declaration, in the order that they
>   should appear. See “Java Source File Example” on page 19 for an example that includes
>   comments.
>
> 1. **Class/interface documentation comment `(/**...*/)`**
>
>    See “Documentation Comments” on page 9 for
>      information on what should be in this comment.
> 2. **class or interface statement**
> 3. **Class/interface implementation comment `(/*...*/)`, if necessary**
>
>    This comment should contain any class-wide or interface-wide information that wasn’t appropriate for the class/interface documentation comment.
> 4. **Class (static) variables**
>
>    First the public class variables, then the protected, and then the private.
> 5. **Instance variables**
>
>    First public, then protected, and then private.
> 6. **Constructors**
> 7. **Methods**
>
>    These methods should be grouped by functionality rather than by scope or accessibility. For example, a private class method can be in between two public instance methods. The goal is to make reading and understanding the code easier.

That said, this convention is quite dated, and the fine print usually not followed. For instance, it seems weird to order fields by accessiblity, but methods by functionality. Indeed, I rarely see fields ordered by accessiblity in professional code. The ordering of the bullet points is adhered to quite universally in professional code, though.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `the only` convention how to organize your class sources.

The structure you listed is very common - attributes first, then constructors and then methods. However, some teams like to keep attributes in the tail of the class, some teams are mixing field definition with its setters and getters.

Team should agree internally on some convention to keep all its sources looking similarly.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Oracle's convention is no more authoritative than any other one, only the Java Language Specification is authoritative, and the team/project local convention is the one and the **only** one that one should follow.

Comment: I would also like to put your comment when you're downvoting me

Comment: Not my downvote, but: There are conventions. You may not agree with them, they may not even agree with each other, but they exist, and the OP is asking for them ("I expect sources").

Comment: Ok, when I said there are no convention I meant there's no `the only` convention. I've fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As with every language, there's no authoritative source other than the language specification (if it exists), and the team or project local conventions. The Java Language Specification does not impose a specific ordering of the members.

Comment: I think the Oracle Coding conventions are a good source for widely spread coding convetions. And I don't think that language specification is related to coding convetions in any other way that all coding convetions have to operate in the field that is allowed by the language specification. The language specification says what's valid code, the convetions say whats good code.

Comment: Being widely spread and, by the way, conventions does not make them widely spread conventions, because most projects don't reject your contributions for the mere fact that you violate them. I recognize that they're good coding practices, but I fail to see how something that is not imposed can be called a coding convention of that project...

Answer (score 0):

You could use tool like Checkstyle (http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/).

It contains some checks for class structure (for example order of modifiers http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_modifier.html, naming conventions http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_naming.html, etc).

This is not the nicest way how to present coding conventions. But the practical advantage is that Checkstyle can be be used directly in your IDE or automated builds so your students can see them applied directly to their code.

Answer (score -1):

I can't back this up but I believe that declaring the member variable in the beggining of a class followed by constructors is the only "convention" applicable to all languages. I use quotes because it is done naturally as if it is the only logical way to place them in the object definition (unlike otherthings e.g. C++ style brackets etc)